# data transfer from one contract to another

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, dapps

I have deployed one contract in my private blockchain, now client has asked  some modification to existing contract and after changes we redeployed this into ethereum network and I got new contract address. Now can we migrate some data from previous contract address to newly deployed contract.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can. If you have provided the ability for such a migration. Some addOldData(...) method. Or if there is no migration method, then, may be, you can repeat all requests - same as to previous contract. Or, may be in old contract you have getData() method - then you can call it from new contract or from application level.

If no options above are not available for you, then create a new contract with these methods and deploy it again.

In a worst case, if you have much of data in old contract and no methods to gain the data - you still can obtain them by other means - tools (libs) for blockchain analisys. All the contract's data are public, so it should be possible.

Answer (score 0):

of course you can, just transfer the data from your previous contract to your new contract by using defined methods.